# Direct access to guarded routes on Angular app, .net hosted

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angular

I have implemented routes like this with LazyLoading, this is just an example.

```
   {
        path: 'user',
        loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule',
        data: {
          label: 'User',
          permissions: [UserRole.Admin]
        }
      }
```

They are all protected with `canActivate` guard, so i can't access it being someone except '`Admin`' most of time.

On back end side in development mode i am using angularCliServer or proxy, from time to time.

```
  app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                //if (env.IsDevelopment())
                //    spa.UseAngularCliServer("start");

                //if (env.IsDevelopment())
                //{
                //spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
               // }

            });
```

But when i comment all options, i can access my routes via hitting direct link

```
localhost:4200/user
```

So all my routes are accessable and editable, i think this is some kind of security problem on .net side, but i have no expertise in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share whats inside of your `canActivate` guard

Comment: There can be anything, even if I just return false (restrict all of them), behaviour still the same.